# Como comparar dígito por dígito campos numérico de izquierda a derecha

Tags: java

Buenas tengo este codigo que es de un juego de adivinar en el cual te dice cuantos dígitos tienes bien puesto

```
public class adivinar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Entorno:

        int numeroAdivinar;
        int numeroSecreto;
        int numeroAdvAux;
        int numeroSeAux;
        byte contador;
        byte contadorDigito = 0;
        int cifrasAdivinar = 0;
        boolean ganador = false;
        int numeroAdvAA;
        int numeroSeAA;
        //Algoritmo:   
        System.out.println("Turno del Primer Jugador");
        do {
            System.out.println("Introduzca un numero por teclado");
            numeroAdivinar = Leer.datoInt();
        } while (numeroAdivinar <= 0);
        contador = 0;
        numeroAdvAux = numeroAdivinar;
        while (numeroAdvAux != 0) {             
            numeroAdvAux = numeroAdvAux / 10;        
            contadorDigito++;         
        }

        System.out.println("Turno del Segundo Jugador");
        do {
            do {
                System.out.println("Introduzca el segundo numero");
                numeroSecreto = Leer.datoInt();
            } while (numeroSecreto <= 0);
            numeroAdvAux = numeroAdivinar;
            numeroSeAux = numeroSecreto;
            if (numeroAdvAux == numeroSeAux) {

                ganador = true;

            } else {

                for (int i = 0; i < contadorDigito; i++) {

                    numeroAdvAA = numeroAdvAux % 10;
                    numeroSeAA = numeroSeAux % 10;

                    if (numeroAdvAA == numeroSeAA) {
                        cifrasAdivinar += 1;
                    }
                    numeroAdvAux = numeroAdvAux / 10;
                    numeroSeAux = numeroSeAux / 10;

                }
                System.out.println("Has introducido un total de: " + cifrasAdivinar + " digitos bien colocados");
                cifrasAdivinar = 0;

            }

            contador = (byte) (contador + 1);
        } while (contador != 10 && ganador != true);
        if (ganador) {
            System.out.println("Has acertado todas las cifras");

        } else {
            System.out.println("Se te acabaron las oportunidades ");
        }
    }
}
```

Pero no sé como podría hacerlo para que comparece el número por la izquierda y no por la derecha como lo hago

Comment: hola amigo, que quieres hacer exactamente, yo puedo ayudarte :3

Comment: en ves de que me compare los numeros por la derecha, que empiece a comparar digito a digito por la izquierda.

Comment: no te entiendo, explicate bien

Comment: 123 y 555123 me da un total de 3 cifras correctas, pero yo quiero que me de mal, por que esa comparacion empieza a comparar por el digito de la derecha en ves de por la izquierda, 123 y 123555 tendría que dar un total de 3 digitos bien colocados

Comment: has probado a pasar el entero a string, con un `split()` separar los caracteres y guardarlos en una matriz, y despues recorrer esa matriz de manera inversa comparando los numeros?

Answer (score 1):

```
    int numero=34346634;
    //Creamos matriz con todos los caracteres por separado
    String[] numString=String.valueOf(numero).split(""); 
    // Recorremos el array(leemos el numero caracter a caracter de izquierda a derecha)
    for(int i=0;i<numString.length;i++){ 
     //Por cada caracter hacemos la comprobacion pertinente
       if(Integer.parseInt(numString[i])==numero_a_comprobar){ 

      }
    }
```

Con esto pasas un numero a `String`, lo trozeas con el método `split()` en cada uno de sus caracteres y lo metes en un `Array`, de esta manera puedes recorrer el array que sería como ir leyendo el numero dígito a dígito empezando por la izquierda.

Si especificas un poco mas el problema, te aporto algo mas. Pero con lo que has puesto en tu pregunta no queda muy claro que es lo que necesitas.